# Gradient color datapoints in scatterplot

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using a dataset that has three columns, first column being dates and the second column being the xaxis data, and third column being the yaxis data corresponding to those dates.

Is there a way to plot the datapoints such that they are plotted light to dark as we plot from the very first date in the dataset to today?

Comment: It looks like this has been dealt with before.  Search for "Coloring each point of a chart based on data using sequential or divergent color scales" and "How can I color dots in a xy scatterplot according to column value?" and I think you'll find what you need.  Interesting problem.  I think I'll invent a need for it, just so I can try it out :)  Sorry, I'm not good at posting links directly to the questions.  I'll work on that too :)

Comment: @Hrothgar Thank you!